# Google sheets script - not picking up negative numbers in column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, numbers

I'm using the following script in a google sheet that i copied
it should add up all the amount in the column 15 starting from row 3, but it doesn't look at all at negative numbers it just skips it.
i'm new at this scripting and i only adjusted the get range.

Should i somehow adjust the following line         `if (parseFloat(values[i]) > 0)`

I tried "!=" but that gives "#NUM!"
changeing 0 into -100000 works but that is a work around

I would be very greatfull if someone could help me out.

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var performanceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Performance');
  var rng = performanceSheet.getRange(3,15,performanceSheet.getLastRow());
  var values = rng.getValues()
  var total = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (parseFloat(values[i]) > 0) {
      total = total + parseFloat(values[i]);
```

Comment: Just remove the if. Your should consider learning JavaScript before learning google apps script

Comment: thanks i'm still very green at this and i wanted to use this script now and not after a long time when i know JavaScript and then then google script differences

Comment: that was the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
if (parseFloat(values[i]) > 0) {
```

and the other:

```
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this should work when all the lines in the column are filled with a value but i have many empty columns so I get a NUM error. I think i just leave it at > -1000000 as that will be never reached

Comment: This answer is correct since you didn't mention there were empty cells. Just add an `if` to discard empty cells `!= " "`.